# CSS fixed element appears underneath content

Tags: html, css

I have a Div element that pops up when clicking on a icon.
This works fine on desktop. But when I'm trying it on mobile it appears underneath the content instead of above, although the elements z-index is set to 5000.

It seems like it only ends up underneath when running on a webkit-based browser. First I thought it was depending on the height of the page but it's only when i'm running chrome in device toolbar and all phones that I've tested.

It should look like this. It's a popup that appears when you click the Info button in the footer:

[image: How it should look]

The css for the box/popup is element with class cms-footer-info is the popup/box:

```
position: fixed;
background-color: #444445;
color: #fff;
height: auto;
display: block;
left: 1%;
bottom: 60px;
padding: 2%;
z-index: 4000;
```

Html for the the footer :

```
<div class="footer">
     <div class="footer-column-one">
        <i class="fa fa-globe fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div class="cms-links">
           <h6>Document identity</h6>
           <div>
              <span class="cms-footer-info-0-label">something</span>
              <span class="cms-footer-info-0-value">else</span>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="cms-footer-center">
        <div class="cms-footer-center-0">Some Text </div>
     </div>
     <div class="footer-column-three">
        <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div class="cms-footer-info">
           <h6>Document identity</h6>
           <div class="cms-footer-info-0">
              <span class="cms-footer-info-0-label">Publ. no. </span>
              <span class="cms-footer-info-0-value">T810181</span>
           </div>
           <div class="cms-footer-info-1">
              <span class="cms-footer-info-1-label">Label</span>
              <span class="cms-footer-info-1-value">Value </span>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

The content underneath the pop up has static layout and has no z-index:

The css:

```
margin-bottom: 65px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
max-width: 700px;
display: block;
```

The html:

```
<div class="container">
   <div>
    Alot of text. Wrapped in spans, divs and so on.
   </div>
</div>
```

Any tips are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Link to working example: [Working example](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cms-responsive/abx-responsive-46/flir11/index.html#styler-id1.3.10.1)

When you have loaded the site. Try pressing the info or globe icon in the bottom. It will show you the relevant popups, now open the developer console and choose toggle device toolbar top left corner in the developer console  in Chrome or visit the url on a phone.

Comment: please provide whole code, i.e. the html too

Comment: provide jsfiddle?

Comment: I've added som html, I will check with my customer if it's ok to upload it to aws s3 so you could watch the real example.

Comment: Please provide a working fiddle example fo your code.

Comment: Added link to a exampel: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cms-responsive/abx-responsive-46/flir11/index.html#styler-idu1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take out the `overflow:hidden;` from the footer. it solved it for me.